# Short horror story where man's subconscious gives him phone-calls

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, richard-matheson

So I was reading "I Am Legend" and when I finished it I found a couple more extra short horror stories tied in within the book so I assume they were also written by Richard Matheson. The name of the last story was literally unreadable (It was covered with black block thingies) because apparently whoever was printing it messed up big time.

The story is about this dude named David Meerman (Or something like that) and he keeps hearing a ringing in his ears at night. He pretends to pick up a telephone and a voice who acts as various people (Including a government agent, an inventor, his deceased father, and an evil spirit) taunts him over the telephone in his mind. David's therapist (Called Palmer) suggests that the voice is actually his subconsciousness trying to communicate with him and urges David to fight back against the voice and defend himself.

David also gets an exorcist who convinces him that he's being possessed but when he tells Palmer Palmer insists that its not the case.

So one night David decides to confront the voice but it starts laughing manically. David tries to hang up on the pretend telephone to shut the voice up but it doesn't work and the voice continues to mock him. David takes some sleeping pills and falls asleep.

More stuff happened after that but I didn't understand any of it so I tried googling an explanation of the story online. I tried everything else I could think of but I can't even find the name of the story.

Someone help me find the name of this story! Help!!

(PS Some stuff might be inaccurate because I was reading a translated version)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Person to Person](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51031). I read it in Matheson's anthology [Backteria and Other Improbable Tales](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?416497) though the ISFDB entry showsit has been included in several editions of *I am Legend*. The protagonist is *David Millman* not *Meerman*, and the doctor is indeed *Dr. Palmer*.

Comment: thanks! could you also explain the ending for me? I didn't get it

Comment: @Hi0401: My interpretation of it was that the voice took over, and is narrating the ending, while Millman pleads to be let back into his head again. Either he took too many pills, died, and the voice (maybe a demon) took over, or it was the last bit where he asked to be removed from his head, and it did so, letting the voice take over.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Ahh I see.